# VBA , MS Excel. Update combo box value on change

Tags: vba, excel

How do I (on 'Continue' button click) make it pass current string from comboBox@userForm in to excel document cell and close form ?

My current code doesn't work properly. It doesn't update combo box value on change and always return original ("Select subtype") value.

 **Here's my module code :**

```
Public main As Integer, i As Integer, temp As String, x As String

Public Sub dataValidation()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 3 To 22
    Select Case Cells(i, 6).Value
        Case "Income"
            main = 1
            If Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then
                Cells(i, 7).Value = getData
            End If
        Case ...
        End Select
Next i

End Sub


Public Function getData()

    UserForm1.Show
    x = UserForm1.cboSubtype.Value
    getData = x

End Function
```

**And my form code:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With cboSubtype
    '.Value = "Select subtype"'

    Select Case main
        Case 1
            .AddItem "Parents"
            .AddItem "Grant"

        Case 2
            .AddItem "Food"
            .AddItem "Drink"

        Case 3
            .AddItem "Books"
            .AddItem "Fees"

    End Select
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? when you select a value from the Combo-Box what do you want to happen ? what is the purpose of your function `getData()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to adopt these minor modifications

- Userform code pane

  ```
  Private Sub Continue_Click()
      Me.Hide
  End Sub

  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

      With Me.cboSubtype
          '.Value = "Select subtype"'

          Select Case mainVal
              Case 1
                  .AddItem "Parents"
                  .AddItem "Grant"

              Case 2
                  .AddItem "Food"
                  .AddItem "Drink"

              Case 3
                  .AddItem "Books"
                  .AddItem "Fees"

          End Select
      End With
  End Sub
  ```
- Module code

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Public mainVal As Integer

  Public Sub dataValidation()

      Dim i As Integer

      For i = 3 To 22
          Select Case Cells(i, 6).value
              Case "Income"
                  mainVal = 1
                  If Cells(i, 7).value = "" Then Cells(i, 7).value = getData
      '        Case ...
              End Select
      Next i

  End Sub


  Public Function getData()

      With UserForm4
          .Show
          getData = .cboSubtype.value
      End With
      Unload UserForm4

  End Function
  ```